# How to fetch the tables list in database in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I need to list out the tables in database, I found this query

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE  'merTrans%'
```

to get the tables but how could I use the `foreach` to get the table names in Laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To list out the tables in database you can do

```
$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
foreach($tables as $table)
{
      echo $table->Tables_in_db_name;
}
```

You'll have to change the db_name to the name of your database.

**EDIT : FOR LIKE CASES**

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    foreach ($table as $key => $value)
        echo $value;
}
```

Comment: without like condition it's working fine. But if i add the "LIKE  'merTrans%' "    Undefined property: stdClass::$Tables_in_db_name.

Comment: Double foreach for something like this seems rather unnecessary?

Comment: Note, this answer will only work for MySQL. OP is using MySQL based on the syntax, but this will not work, for instance, in an Sqlite3 or Postgresql database.

Comment: $tableNames = collect(DB::select('SHOW TABLES'))->map(function($val) {  return head($val); });

Answer (score 72):

I've been using this:

`$tables = DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames();`

It requires doctrine/dbal as a dependency. But some migration features already need DBAL to work.

Comment: I prefer this one because I don't have to deal with the different DB grammars.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Awesome answer, this one should be accepted one!

Comment: A short and sweet solution to get all the table names from a database out of the box. Thanks @carlosvini

Comment: thanks. i have to  execute `composer req doctrine/dbal` first. (if not yet installed)

Answer (score 35):

To get a quick array containing all databases you can use the following piece of code:

```
// Iterate over the results of SHOW TABLES
// strip off all the objects and keys.
$tables = array_map('reset', \DB::select('SHOW TABLES'));
```

To me this seems to be the most elegant solution.

Comment: <3 this one.. #L55

Comment: Perfect answer and the most elegant way to handle this. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

**For Postgres Users:**

`SHOW TABLES` is not supported so you have to do something a bit more hackey.

```
$tables = DB::select("SELECT table_schema,table_name, table_catalog FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_catalog = 'YOUR TABLE CATALOG HERE' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema = 'public' ORDER BY table_name;")
```

Make sure you fill out table_catalog (which I guess is equatable to database).  You may have to tweak your results a bit.

Comment: I would argue "SHOW TABLES" is the hack.  information_schema is the standard way to do this.

Comment: To follow the original question, LIKE condition needs to be added: `AND table_name LIKE 'merTrans%'`

Answer (score 7):

In Laravel you can use:

```
$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$tables = \DB::select("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'merTrans%'");
foreach ($tables as $table) {
  echo head($table);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack since Laravel's [`head` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-head) was supposed to work with arrays and not objects, but it work because it basically calls `reset` on the parameter called to it...

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to apply some migration changes to all tables.

In Laravel 6 `Schema::getAllTables()` became a public method, so
 you can do something like this:

```
$tables = array_filter(
    Schema::getAllTables(),
    static function ($table) {
        return preg_match('/some_(\d+)_table/', $table->{'Tables_in_' . env('DB_DATABASE')});
    }
);

foreach ($tables as $table ) {
    Schema::table(
        $table->{'Tables_in_' . env('DB_DATABASE')},
        static function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->removeColumn('request_id');
        }
    );
}
```

That's relevant when you need to do (in my case above - remove a column) something with tables that have this naming structure: `some_1_table`, `some_2_table`, `some_3_table`, etc.
So basically instead of `DB::select('SHOW TABLES');` you can now use `Schema::getAllTables()`.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution will be, you do not need to use DB name. 'current' will take first column only.

```
function getTables()
{
    $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');

    $tables = array_map('current',$tables);

    return $tables;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this to get all tables with columns:

```
$schema = collect(DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames())->map(function ($item, $key) {
  return [
    'name' => $item,
    'columns' => DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($item)
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I don't have the reputation to add a comment, yet, I'm posting this as an answer.

A recommendation for Bharat's LIKE CASES

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    echo array_shift(array_values($table));
}
```

if you don't like having a double foreach, but make sure you var_dump $table,

```
($tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
```

to see exactly what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected function getNamesTablesDB(){

        $database = Config::get('database.connections.mysql.database');

        $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');

        $combine = "Tables_in_".$database;

        $collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

        foreach($tables as $table){
            $collection->put($table->$combine, $table->$combine);
        }

        return $collection; //or compact('collection'); //for combo select
    }
```

Comment: This answer's work for mysql. I would have upvote it if had some comments on how n why should this work.

Answer (score 1):

Find the ***list of tables*** from your database in **"Laravel"**

```
        $tables_list = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
        
        foreach($tables_listas $value)
        {
              echo $value->Tables_in_YourDatabaseName;
        }
```

'***Tables_in_YourDatabaseName***' means : for example if your database name is **"test"**
then

echo $value->Tables_in_test;

Answer (score 1):

```
public function hiddenTables()
   {
       return [
            'migrations',
            'password_resets',
       ];
   }



public function dbTables()
    {
        foreach (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select('SHOW TABLES') as $tables) {
            foreach ($tables as $table => $value)
                $db[] = $value;
        }

        return $db;
    }



public static function diffTables()
    {
        return array_diff((new self)->dbTables(), (new self)->hiddenTables());
    }
```

Comment: Please consider to add also some word comments why the code solves the problem, not only the code.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use information_schema.tables to get list of table names.

```
function getTableNames($db_name, $search = ''){
        $rows = DB::select("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{$db_name}' AND table_name like '%{$search}%'");

        $table_names = [];
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            $table_names[] = $row->table_name;
        }

        return $table_names;
}

print_r(getTableName('my_db', 'merTrans'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot pass `'reset'` into `array_map` anymore this is my solution:

```
$tables = array_map(fn($item) => $item->{array_keys(get_object_vars($item))[0]}, DB::select('SHOW TABLES'))
```

Answer (score -1):

For those, who like to use the query builder:

```
DB::table('sqlite_master')
    ->whereIn('type', [ 'table', 'view' ])
    ->where('name', 'NOT LIKE', 'sqlite_%')
    ->orderBy('1')
    ->pluck('name')
    ->all()
```

Answer (score -4):

Add flowing thing in your Laravel project :-
In Controller file :-

```
 public function debate_list(){
         $records = DB::table('table_name')->get();
        return view('page_link')->with('records',$records);
    }
```

In page_link.blade.php add flowing :-

```
@foreach($records as $class)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$class->id}}</td>
    <td>
      {{$class->name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{$class->image_url}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ $class->created_at }}
    </td>

    <td>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " href="{{route('image_status_list')}}"> VIEW</a>
    </td>

  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer is even related to the question.