# How get the name of all tables with properties in the laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, package

I want to make a laravel admin package and I want to make the dynamic panel with the dynamic role ,for this purpose **`I need a way to get the all table names with their properties`**, so what is the suitable way to get this data in laravel? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question has already been asked and answered:
you can take a look here : [How to fetch the tables list in database in Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478988/how-to-fetch-the-tables-list-in-database-in-laravel-5-1)

I think that should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (config('database.default') == 'pgsql') {
        $database_name = 'laravel';
        $tables = DB::select("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'");

        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $tablename = $table->table_name;
            if ($tablename == 'model_has_permissions' || $tablename == 'password_resets'|| $tablename == 'model_has_roles' 
                || $tablename == 'model_has_permissions'|| $tablename == 'role_has_permissions') {
                continue;
            }
                DB::select("
                SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('$table->table_name' , 'id'), coalesce(max(id)+1, 1), false)
                FROM ".$tablename.";
            ");
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).